# Calling method in MyActivity from a listener class

Tags: methods, ontouchlistener

I am having trouble tying a layoutswipe listener with a method that updates the bakground image on a view.

The two seperate components are working in isolation - i.e.:
1) I have a listener in a 'LayoutSwipeListener" Class that picks up gestures on a layout. This listener is working ok.
2) I have a method in the MainActivity called 'updateWallpaperForward" which updates the background image on a layoutview.

However, what I want to do is call the "updateWallpaperForward" method from my LayoutSwipeListener Class. I can't do this. It currently compiles but the app crashes when I swipe.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

The relevant code is below:

CLASS: MyActivity.java

```
//Layout for wallpaper change
LinearLayout WallpaperLayout;
....
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
//Wallpaper layout
WallpaperLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wallpaperLayout);
WallpaperLayout.setOnTouchListener(new LayoutSwipeListener(this));
...
public void updateWallpaperForward(View view) {
    switch(wallpaperID) {
        case 1:
            WallpaperLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wallpapertwo);
            wallpaperID=2;
            break;
  ...
```

CLASS: LayoutSwipeListener.java

```
  public class LayoutSwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

            private Activity activity;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    public int wallpaperID = 1;

     //Layout for wallpaper change
    LinearLayout WallpaperLayout;

    // private MainActivity mMainActivity;

    public LayoutSwipeListener (Activity mainActivity) {
        activity = mainActivity;
    }
......

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
        activity.updateWallpaperForward();  
         //// THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK - IT DOESNT PICK Up THIS METHOD IN THE EDITOR OR COMPILE
```

Comment: Just to add - I've tried making the method static but that doesn't work as it has fields that cannot be referenced if it is static.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
    public LayoutSwipeListener (Activity mainActivity) {
        activity = mainActivity;
        WallpaperLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.wallpaperLayout); // THIS IS THE LINE I NEEDED
    }
```

Thanks,